# 加藤楸邨の俳句の解釈とその説明

Tags: haiku

> 白き蘭やがて匂へり見つつあれば

白き蘭  ＝そのまま白い蘭
やがて  ＝現代のやがてと同じ意味だと理解しました。
匂へり  ＝可能形の終止形？
見つつあれば　＝現代では「見つつ」は「見ながら」になると思うけど、「見続ける」と理解し、「あれば」はそれを「し続けていれば」にするための必要な文法だと推測しました。

`白い蘭を見続けていたらやがて匂えた`というような意味だと思います。
まず、この解釈は正しいでしょうか？
この解釈が正しいとしても古文が苦手でどうしてこの意味になるのかはっきり分かりません。

`白い蘭を見続けていたらやがて匂えて来た`
の方が自然だと思いますが、「匂えて`来た`」にすることは厳密に言うと間違いでしょうか？

`だれでも蘭を見続けていたらやがて匂えて来るよ`的な意味にならないのは、文法によることですか？それとも俳句の特徴として主観的な立場から書いていることが前提だからでしょうか？

Comment: -eri: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17750/7810

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「白き蘭やがて匂へり見つつあれば」

ほな、始めまひょか・・

> 白き蘭 ＝そのまま白い蘭

その通りです。しかし、この「白」という花の色が大きなポイントとなります。後ほど説明しますが、@By137さんはこの色の重要性に気づかれていないのではという気がしてなりません。

> やがて ＝現代のやがてと同じ意味だと理解しました。

問題ないでしょう。

> 匂へり ＝可能形の終止形？

現代文の「匂う/匂える」をベースに分析していませんか？

古文の普通動詞「匂ふ」の完了形と捉えるべきでしょう。「～た」、「～てしまった」の意味になります。

**更に大きな問題は、@By137さんが古文の「匂ふ」と現代文の「匂う」の意味が同様であることを前提にこの俳句を分析していると思われる点にあります。古文での「匂ふ」は「美しく映える」、「美しく染まる」という意味なのです**。

「見続けていたら、白い蘭が匂いだした」では俳句として成立しません。視覚的なインパクトに欠けるからです。

「見続けていたら、白いはずの蘭にきれいな色が付いた」という意味であるからこそ、俳句として世に残る秀逸性が生まれるのです。空想上の「色の変化」を表現しています。これが上述した「視覚的インパクト」なのです。

もちろん、すべて作者の主観の世界での出来事ですが、読者がこの俳句に共感を持つことで、そこに普遍性が生まれることは言うまでもありません。

Comment: ありがとうございます！本当に聞いてよかったと思います！実は蘭の匂いが薄くて分かる人は殆どいないという情報があったから、「見続けていたらないはずの香りがしてきた」という意味になって、俳句として成立していると思ってしまいました。これからは古文辞典を片手に俳句の解釈に挑む必要があることがよく分かりました。